# How can I see the delayed job queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I wonder if I succeeded to get [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) working.
Can't see jobs in the `delayed_jobs` table.

- Is that normal?
- Is there any other ways too see job queue?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

DelayedJob stores a database record for each enqueued job so you can retrieve them directly through the rails console (assuming you are using ActiveRecord or similar).

Open the rails console:

```
$ rails c
```

and then query the enqueued jobs:

```
Delayed::Job.all
```

or

```
Delayed::Job.last
```

Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details).

If you installed delayed_job with another database like Redis you may want to go and check in there the queued jobs.

Comment: How can i start a Delayed::Worker on specific queue in test cases?

Answer (score 9):

You should see jobs in the delayed_jobs table, yes. But when delayed jobs are run successfully they're deleted. So it may just be a fleeting thing. (Delayed Job checks the table for new jobs to run every 5 seconds, so the record may only last a few seconds on average given a short-running job.) I usually make sure the delayed job daemon is turned off if I want to inspect the payload objects in the delayed_jobs table.

Comment: Failed jobs are deleted by default, but Delayed::Job can be configured to keep them around.